# download files in a single progress bar

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progress-bar

I have a progress bar managed by a `AsyncTask` which downloads some files from the internet.

```
private class DownloadImgs extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                showDialog(progress_bar_type);
            }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void ...params) {
               for(GetCountry gc : listCountry){
           getdownloadedFiles(gc.getUrl());}

           return null;

            }


            protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

                pDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
           }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);


            }
```

The method which allows me to download the files:

```
public void getdownloadedFiles(String url)

            {

                int count;
                 try {

                  URL urlImg = new URL(url);
                  URLConnection connection = urlImg.openConnection();
                  connection.connect();

                  int lenghtOfFile = connection.getContentLength();
                  InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(urlImg.openStream(), 8192);


                  OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(folder+"/"+name);

                  byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                  long total = 0;

                  while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                      total += count;

                     publishProgress(""+(int)((total*100)/lenghtOfFile));

                      output.write(data, 0, count);

                  }


                  output.flush();           
                  output.close();
                  input.close();

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.getMessage();
                 }


            }
```

This code works well, but the problem is that each file downloaded has it's own progress bar
I want only one progress bar for all the downloaded files.

How can I achieve this?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `doInBackground()` method, simply loop over the list of files you need to download inside of the single execution of your `AsyncTask`.  You should probably also leverage the varargs nature of `execute()` to pass the list of URLs you need to download.  In other words, something close to this:

```
DownloadImgs task = new DownloadImgs();
task.execute(url1, url2, url3, url4, url5);
```

The modify the task as such:

```
private class DownloadImgs extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String ...params) {

        for (String url : params) {
            getdownloadedFiles(url);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void getdownloadedFiles(String url) {
        /* Existing code */
    }

    /* Other methods unchanged */
}
```

**EDIT:**

One method you could use to display all the file downloads as a single contiguous progress indicator is simply to update the progress by file count alone rather than file content.  In other words, if you have 5 files just `publishProgress()` with values of 20 (1 * 100 / 5), 40 (2 * 100 / 5), 60 (3 * 100 / 5), 80 (4 * 100 / 5), and 100 (5 * 100 / 5) at the end of each file download.

If you need something more granular without pre-fetching the content length of every file, make each chunk increment with percentage.  Note that you can also set the maximum level of the progress bar with `setMax()` to something other than 100 to make the math easier to work with.  In the same 5 files example, you can set the progress bar maximum to 500, and for each download you would still add 100 to the total in the same fashion as you are now, but the total does not reset at the beginning of each download.

Comment: @Devunwinred Thank you very much for your help but the problem is that by doing so there will be as many progress bar as downloaded files. I want only one progressbar showed for all files. I think i need to calculate the total lengh files of all downloaded files before call publish progress?

Comment: So your problem is not multiple progress bars then, but rather that the progress bar reset with each download and you want it to display the overall operation progress for all files.  I have edited with some thoughts.

Comment: Thank you very much . You was very helpful. It works great now

Answer (score 0):

Pass multiple URLs to your async task.

```
new DownloadImgs().execute(URL1,URL2,URL3);
```

it will show whole progress as a single progress bar.

Comment: This cannot be done.  Any `AsyncTask` instance can only be run once.  Calling `execute()` again will throw an exception.

Comment: pass all the urls of files you want to download.