# A method is running after execution of other lines

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jprogressbar

I have a program that downloads a file on a button click and I wanted to show the download percentage on a progress bar but the progress bar was not updating and I used a void class for it to not be in the doInBackground method of a swing worker but when I run the code It first downloads the file and after the downloading shows a message and not running the progress bar update method alongside the download method, so I searched google and found out that I could use Threads but When I use the threads It doesn't execute any method in threads.
Here is my code with threads:

```
package mcsm;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import static mcsm.MCSM1.jLabel2;
import static mcsm.MCSM1.jProgressBar1;
public class download {
    static SwingWorker sw1 = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
            String fileName = "Hi.jar";
            File spigotjar = new File(fileName);
            
            if (!(spigotjar.exists())) {
                Thread dlth = new Thread() {
                    public void rundl() throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("Downloading !?!");
                        URL url = new URL("Some URL");
                        try (InputStream in = url.openStream(); ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel( in ); FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("Hi.jar")) {
                            fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                            urlConnection.connect();
                            System.out.println("Wait, thats illegal.");
                        }
                    }
                };
                Thread dlpr = new Thread() {
                    public void prdl() throws Exception {
                        dlprogress();
                    }
                };
                dlth.start();
                dlpr.start();
            }
            if (spigotjar.exists()) {
                Fileexists();
                System.out.println("Hey ?!");
            }
            String res = "Finished Execution";
            return res;
        }
    };
    public static void Fileexists() {
        jLabel2.setText("The file exists already !");
    }
    public static void dlprogress() throws Exception {
        String fileName = "Hi.jar";
        File spigotjar = new File(fileName);
        URL url = new URL("Some more URL");
        jLabel2.setText("Downloading the file from Bukkit website....");
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        int dl_size = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        int dlsize_kb = dl_size / 1024;
        int dlsize_mb = dlsize_kb / 1024;
        long file_sizel = spigotjar.length();
        int file_size = (int) file_sizel;
        float file_size_kb = file_size / 1024;
        float file_size_mb = file_size_kb / 1024;
        float total_per_multi = 100 / dlsize_mb;
        float percentage = file_size_mb * total_per_multi;
        while (file_size != dl_size) {
            jProgressBar1.setValue((int) percentage);
            System.out.println("Working Fine....");
        }
        while (file_size == dl_size) {
            jProgressBar1.setValue(0);
            jLabel2.setText("Download Finished!");
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if its not clear my prime language is not english.

Comment: Why are you using 2 threads and connections here? Why don't you extract the content length from the download url, transfer bytes in a loop and update the progress bar in a single thread?

Comment: If I do Them without swing workers it will freeze the window till the download is done and if use the method in a swing worker it wont update the swing components so I have to use them in another void method and call it from the swing worker doinbackground method

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453643/java-progress-bar-and-download

Comment: @Abra so Whats problem of my code ?!

Comment: "If I do Them without swing workers..." - that's now what I suggested. My question was why you are using 2 worker threads instead of one as the task is basically the same. Of course you'd have to refactor the actual download code to some extent. - Finally, note you're actually using 3 threads: the SwingWorker you're using runs the associated task in yet another thread (apart from the EDT).

Answer (score 1):

```
Thread dlpr = new Thread() {
      // changed prdl() --> run()
      public void run() throws Exception {
             dlprogress();
      }
};
```

This Anonymous Inner class created by you which is extending Thread class needs to override run() method . Because on calling **dlpr.start()** internally run() method is called.
Can you please try changing you method name to run() in both the threads.